# error in nonero rpc wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc

im running a monero node with rpc wallet . everything was working fine but suddenly im getting an error

2023-11-17 17:27:13.400 E WRONG DATA CONVERSION: from type=d to type m
2023-11-17 17:27:13.401 E Exception on unserializing: WRONG DATA CONVERSION: from type=d to type m